# Order of $g^i$ in cyclic group of order $n$

Tags: group-theory

I am very new to groups and still have problems with proving some basic facts. I stumbled on such theorem:

> Let $g$ be a generator of cyclic group of order $n$. Then $g^i$ has order $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,i)}$

And I'm frustrated with no ideas how to prove it. Clearly $g$ has order $n$, so $g^n=1$. We are looking for the smallest $d$, such that $(g^i)^d=1$. So $id  \ | \ n$ or $n \ | \ id$ ? I suppose the first case, but don't see exactly why. Am I on the right direction? Can anybody help what to do next?

Comment: You should prove that $g^i$ to the stated power is $1$, then show if $(g^i)^d=1$, then $n/\gcd(n,i)\mid d$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/order-of-an-element-in-a-finite-cyclic-group, which has a very nice proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(g^i)^d=g^{id}$.  Noting $\text{ord}\ {g}=n$, if $g^{id}=e$, $n|id$.  Note that $id$ is then, by definition, $\text{lcm} (n,i)$.  Moreover, $\text{lcm}(n,i)\gcd(n,i)=n\cdot i$.

I'll let you finish the proof.