# On the order of elements in a finite cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this proof:

[Order of an element in a finite cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/order-of-an-element-in-a-finite-cyclic-group?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Of which I don't understand the last step where it is claimed:

> $| \langle a^k \rangle| = |\{1, a^d, a^{2d}, \ldots, a^{m-d} \}| = m/d$

Particularly, how $a^{m-d}$ is the element of highest power non equal to identity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the proof it is shown that $\langle a^k \rangle = \{a^{nd}, n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. But the latter set is just $\{1, a^d,a^{2d},\dots,a^{(\frac{m}{d}-1)d}\}$, since $a^{\frac{m}{d}d}=a^{m}=1$. And of course $(\frac{m}{d}-1)d = m - d$. Hope that answers your question!