# Let $a \in G$ be a finite ordered element and let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $a$ and $a^n$ have equal orders iff $\gcd\big(n, o(a)\big)=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group and let $a \in G$ be a finite ordered element and let $n$ be an arbitrary integer. Prove that $a^n$ is also a finite ordered element. Prove that $a$ and $a^n$ have equal orders if and only if $\gcd\big(n, o(a)\big) = 1$.

I managed to prove the first part, but didn't manage to prove the second part.

*Proof of first part:* Observe that $\langle a^n\rangle = \{(a^n)^p \  | \ p \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{(a^{n\cdot p}) \  | \ p \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \langle a \rangle = \{a^m \ | m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and since $o(a)$ is finite we have $\langle a \rangle$ to be finite and thus $\langle a^n \rangle $ to be finite. Since $o(a^n)$ is the cardinilatity of the set $\langle a^n \rangle $ we have $o(a^n)$ to be finite and thus $a^n$ is also a finite ordered element. $\square$

Firstly, is my proof above satisfactory? Secondly I am not sure how to go about proving the second part of the problem, how could one prove the second part of this problem?

Comment: I think it is "finite order" element or "element of finite order". It does not have to do with ordering but with cardinality.

Comment: This follows immediately from the result in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks correct, but there is perhaps an easier way:

Since $o(a)$ is finite, then $(a^{n})^{o(a)}=e$, so $o(a^n)\mid o(a)n$ and $o(a^n)$ is therefore also finite.

For the second part try proving that if $\gcd(o(a),n)=1$ then $o(a)\mid o(a^n)$ and $o(a^n)\mid o(a)$. This will prove that $o(a)=o(a^n)$. Here is a hint, notice that $$a^{o(a^n)n}=e=a^{o(a)n}$$

For the other direction you assume that $$a^{o(a)}=(a^n)^{o(a)}$$ and need to show that $\gcd(o(a),n)=1$. Remember that $o(a)$ is the smallest number such that $a^{o(a)}=e$, what does this tell you about $o(a)n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$o(a^n)=\dfrac{o(a)}{gcd(o(a),n)}$