# Is $\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 :|z_1|=|z_2| = 1, z_1^m = z_2^n\}$ a circle?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry

Fix $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ and consider the subspace
$$
A = \{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 :|z_1|=|z_2| = 1, z_1^m = z_2^n\}
$$
of the $2$-torus. Is this space homeomorphic to a circle?

Thinking of $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ there's a map $S^1 \to A$ given by $z \mapsto (z^n,z^m)$. Is this map obviously bijective?

Comment: If you have to ask, then it's not "obviously" anything ;-).  More seriously, if say, $n = 0$ and $m=2$, then $A = \{(1,z_2)\}\cup \{(-1,z_2)\}$ is disconnected, so not homeomorphic to a circle.  The general result (which you should try to prove) is that $A$ has $\gcd(m,n)$ components, each of which is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: And of course, when $m=n=0,$ it is the whole torus.

Comment: Ahh yes, I should've been clear that I mean't the case where $mn \ne 0$.

Comment: Here's a further hint.  Suppose $\gcd(a,b) = d$.  Let $\mu$ be a fixed primitive $d$-th root of unity.  Show the images of the $d$ maps $z\mapsto (z^n, \mu^k z^m)$ for $0\leq k\leq d-1$ are distinct and lie in $A$.

Comment: I'm struggling to show that these maps are injective. Given $(z_1^n, \mu^{k_1} z_1^m) = (z_2^n, \mu^{k_2} z_2^m)$ I can show that $k_1 = k_2$ but not that $z_1 = z_2$.

Comment: From my previous comment you can deduce that $z_1/z_2$ is both an $n$-th and $m$-th root of unity, and consequently a $\gcd(m,m)$-th root of unity. But I do not see how to deduce that $z_1 = z_2$.

Comment: I think @JasonDeVito's comment should say $(z^{n/d}, \mu^k z^{m/d})$

Comment: (If you don't type @ JasonDeVito (with no space), then I am not notified of your response.  You will notified automatically as the post owner.)   I didn't claim that the maps were injective, just that their images were distinct and that they lie in $A$.  @ronno is correct that if you want them to be injective maps, you need to use his/her formula.  And thanks to ronno for bringing me back to the conversation.

Comment: I have been thinking about my comment where I introduce the $d$ distinct maps, and I now think it is garbage.  The images don't need to be distinct.  Specifically, if we take $n = 4, m = 2$, then $\gcd(n,m) = 2$.  Then $\mu = -1$, and the claim would be that the images of $(z^4,z^2)$ and $(w^4, -w^2)$ have to be distinct.  But they aren't:  The point with $z=1$ is the same as the point with $w= i$.  In fact, if we more generally take $z = iw$, then we find the two images are *identical*.  I'll keep thinking about it and see if I can adjust the comment to something correct.

Comment: I got it.  We don't want $\mu$ to be a primitive $d$-th root of $1$, we want it to be a primitive $n$-th root of $1$.  I'll write a full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix integers $m\neq 0$ and $n$.  Our goal is to find all solutions to the equation $z_1^n = z_2^m$ with $(z_1,z_2)\in T^2$.

As you noted, the curve $S^1\ni z\mapsto (z_1, z_2) = (z^m,z^n)$ parameterizes infinitely many solutions to the equation $z_1^n = z_2^m$.  One can potentially make more solutions via the following procedure:  if $\alpha$ is an $n$-th root of unity and $\beta$ is an $m$-th root of unity, then any point of the form $$(z_1,z_2) = (\alpha z^m, \beta z^n)  \hspace{1 in} (\ast)$$ is also a solution.  We will prove that points of this form comprise all solutions, and we'll figure out all redundancies.

Here is the main result:

> Every solution $(z_1,z_2)$ to the equation $z_1^n = z_2^m$ has a unique description the form $$(z_1,z_2) = (z^m, \beta^k z^n)$$ where $\beta$ is a fixed primitive $|m|$-th root of $1$, $k = 0, 1,..., \gcd(m,n)$,  and where $|z|  = 1$.  In particular, the solution consists of $gcd(m,n)$ pairwse non-intersecting closed curves.

Let's prove it.

**Proposition 1:**  All solutions have the form $(\ast)$.  One can even take $\alpha=1$.

**Proof:**  Suppose $(z_1,z_2)$ solves $z_1^n = z_2^m$.  Because $m\neq 0$, there is an $|m|$-th root of $z_1$.  Choose $z$ to be any such $|m|$-th root of $z_1$.  Then $$(z^n)^m = (z^m)^n = z_1^n = z_2^m.$$  Thus, $z_2\overline{z}^n = \beta$ is an $m$-th root of unity.  Then $$(z^m, \beta z^n) = (z_1, z_2)$$ as claimed.  $\square$

So, we have a way of describing all solutions: every solution has the form $(z_1,z_2) = (z^m, \beta z^n)$ for some $z\in S^1$ and $\beta$ an $m$-th root of unity.

But there can be some redundancy in this description.

**Proposition 2:**  Suppose $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are $|m|$-th roots of unity.  If $\beta_1 = \beta^n \beta_2$ for some $|m|$-th root of unity $\beta$, then the two curves $z\mapsto (z^m, \beta_1 z^n)$ and $w \mapsto (w^m, \beta_2 w^n)$ have precisely the same image.

Conversely, if these two curves intersect in any point, then $\beta_1 = \beta^n \beta_2$ for some $|m|$-th root of unity $\beta$.

**Proof:**  Suppose first that $\beta_1 = \beta^n \beta_2$.  Now, given $w$, set $z = \beta^{-1} w$.  Then $$(z^m, \beta_1 z^n) = ((\beta^{-1} w)^m, \beta_1 (\beta^{-1} w)^n) = (w^m, \beta_1 \beta^{-n} w^n) = (w^m, \beta_2 w^n),$$ so every point on the $w$-paramaterized curve is on the $z$-paramaterized curve.  Given $z$, set $w = \beta z$ to get the reverse inclusion.  This completes the proof of the first statement.

To prove the second, let's assume the two curves intersect.  So we have equality $(z^m, \beta_1 z^n) = (w^m, \beta_2 w^n)$.   From the equation $z^m = w^m$, we conclude that $z = \beta w$ where $\beta$ is an $|m|$-th root of unity.  Substituting this into the second equation $\beta_1 z^n = \beta_2w^n$, we find that $\beta_1 (\beta)^n w^n = \beta_2 w^n$, so that $\beta_1 (\beta)^n = \beta_2$.  $\square$

Here is one way to interpret this.  The set of $|m|$-th roots of unity is isomorphic (as a group) to $\mathbb{Z}_m$.  We have a subgroup $n\mathbb{Z}_m$  (which is automatically normal) given as all elements of the form $n\cdot x$ with $x\in \mathbb{Z}_m$.  Then Proposition $2$ says the solution to the equation $z_1^n = z_2^m$ consists of disjoint closed curves, where the connected components of the solution set are in bijection with $\mathbb{Z}_m/H_n$.  Thus, to count connected components, we need to determine the order of $\mathbb{Z}_m/H_n$.

Of course, to do this, we need only determine the order of $H_n$.  To that end, note that $H_n$ is cyclic generated by $n$ (since $H_n$ is the homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ under the "times $n$" map.)  The order of $H_n$ is therefore the order of $n\in \mathbb{Z}_m$.  From, e.g., [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/order-of-an-element-in-a-finite-cyclic-group), the order is $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}$.  Thus, the order of $\mathbb{Z}_m/H_n$ is $\frac{m}{\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}} = \gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: And each of the maps is $\gcd(m, n)$-to-$1$ from $S^1$ to its image: $(z^m, \beta z^n) = (w^m, \beta w^n)$ iff $(z/w)^m = (z/w)^n = 1$. Therefore each descends to a homeomorphism from $S^1/(\mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m, n)) \cong S^1$.